# how to simulate a transaction before it is mined?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj, state-transition, simulation

My program needs to know how the transactions in the mempool will affect the state when mined. Does anyone know of any tools to help with this?
Is is possible by chaing go ethereum source code?
or should I use another tool?
I want to get simulation result as tenderly.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.tenderly is too slow for simulating.

Comment: Have you tried Ganache and Truffle as suggested in another answer on this question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I haven't tried ganache and truffle, does ganache rapid? the simulation should be perfermed within 0.3 seconds.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Try it and tell us.